Why am I getting a "Permission denied (publickey)" on Azure Ubuntu?
I have an Ubuntu 24.04 server set up on Azure.  The key it generated when I set up the instance works.  I then created a new user (dbrogdon) and generated a new key with the same key type (Ed25519).  Then I copied the public key to ~dbrogdon/.ssh/authorized_keys and change the permissions to the following:
drwx------ 2 dbrogdon dbrogdon 4.0K Jul 24 17:21 .
drwxr-x--- 3 dbrogdon dbrogdon 4.0K Jul 24 17:22 ..
-rw------- 1 dbrogdon dbrogdon  104 Jul 24 17:20 authorized_keys

On my Mac I have the private key with the following perms:
-rw-------  1 dbrogdon  staff   419B Jul 24 10:51 dbrogdon-key.pem

When I try to ssh from my Mac to the server, I get the following:
debug1: Host 'xxxxxxx' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/dbrogdon/.ssh/known_hosts:53
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Here is auth.log for that session:
2024-07-24T18:09:51.877109+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: Connection from 71.205.127.54 port 52988 on 10.1.0.4 port 22 rdomain ""
2024-07-24T18:09:51.877153+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4
2024-07-24T18:09:51.877191+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6
2024-07-24T18:09:51.877240+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
2024-07-24T18:09:51.877917+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 105/65534 [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.877973+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.878017+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.947718+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.947838+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.947929+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.947984+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.948032+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:51.948082+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.033019+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT received [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.044766+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3 [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.044927+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.044976+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.045012+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.045047+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.145161+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3 [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.145271+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.145321+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.145366+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.145417+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.145475+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ext-info-in-auth@openssh.com=<0> [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.325543+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: userauth-request for user dbrogdon service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.325656+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.326541+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "dbrogdon"
2024-07-24T18:09:52.328243+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "71.205.127.54"
2024-07-24T18:09:52.328320+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
2024-07-24T18:09:52.328369+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: kex_server_update_ext_info: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.397374+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: Connection closed by authenticating user dbrogdon 71.205.127.54 port 52988 [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.397473+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
2024-07-24T18:09:52.397793+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
2024-07-24T18:09:52.397848+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: do_cleanup
2024-07-24T18:09:52.397924+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
2024-07-24T18:09:52.398518+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: Killing privsep child 3350
2024-07-24T18:09:52.398567+00:00 xxxxxxx sshd[3349]: debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12

Here is the command I'm using to connect:
ssh -v -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -i ./dbrogdon-key.pem dbrogdon@myhost.com

Is there something I've missed when setting up this user?  I've never had this problem before on other systems so I'm wondering if there's not something that is particular to Azure.

You did not specify what command line options you are using to connect, but based on the log, it appears that you did not specify a key to use on the connection.
For example, if your key is in the ~/.ssh directory, the command should look something like this:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/dbrogdon-key.pem dbrogdon@my-azure-host.azure.com
You can also use an ssh agent to load keys and use them as an alternative, but you did not specify that you loaded your key into an agent. Agents are convenient if you only have a few keys, but as sshd servers do not generally accept more than 5 authentication attempts, this quickly becomes untenable at scale, and you need to specify the keys manually as above.

Per the updated command in your question, you are explicitly specifying PubKeyAuthentication=no, which would disable the public key authentication you are using. PubKeyAuthentication=yes is required for public key authentication to work, and is the default setting, so it would not typically need to be specified.

I just updated the question to add the command but it is essentially that.  I am not using an agent to load the key.

Ok - in your update, you are explicitly specifying PubKeyAuthentication=no, which would disable the public key authentication you are using. PubKeyAuthentication needs to be yes.

Ah, that was it. Thanks!
